# my regexp does not work for a simple word match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to see if the current request is on the localhost or not. For doing this, I use the following regular expression:

```
 return ( preg_match("/(^localhost).*/", $url) == true ||
            preg_match("/^({http|ftp|https}://localhost).*/", $url) == true )
            ? true : false;
```

And here is the `var_dump()` of `$url`:

```
string 'http://localhost/aone/public/' (length=29)
```

Which keeps returning false though. What is the problem of this regular expression?

Comment: What does `$url` contain? Post the output of `var_dump($url);`

Comment: Remove the `{` and `}` from your regex. and use `(...)` instead. Also, you can use a single regex: `~^(?:(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)?localhost).*~`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently using the forward slash (`/`) as the delimiter, but you aren't escaping it inside your pattern string. This will result in an error and will cause your `preg_match()` statement to not work (if you don't have error reporting enabled).

Also, you are using alternation incorrectly. If you want to match either `foo` or `bar`, you'd write `(foo|bar)`, and *not* `{foo|bar}`.

The updated `preg_match()` should look like:

```
preg_match("/^(http|ftp|https):\/\/localhost.*/", $url)
```

Or with a different delimiter (so you don't have to escape all the `/` characters):

```
preg_match("#^(http|ftp|https)://localhost.*#", $url)
```

Comment: No it's not the answer. It matches either `http.*`, OR `ftp.*` OR `:\/\/localhost.*`

Comment: I doubt it works correctly. Only the `http|ftp|https` need to be grouped.

Comment: I think so, I do not know why the OP would expect localhost without protocol in the question, but this answer works for URL with protocol.

Comment: @Jorge: I do not know where the OP is getting this `$url` from, but I think it's just safe to assume it's either `localhost` with or without protocol information (as he's just trying to find out if he's on localhost or not).

Answer (score 2):

Curly braces have a special meaning in a regex, they are used to quantify the preceding character(s).

So:

```
/^({http|ftp|https}://localhost).*/
```

Should probably be something like:

```
#^((http|ftp|https)://localhost).*#
```

**Edit:** changed the delimiters so that the forward slash does not need to be escaped

Comment: Is there a need to group localhost with parenthesis?

Answer (score 1):

This

```
{http|ftp|https}
```

is wrong.

I suppose you mean

```
(http|ftp|https)
```

Also, if you want only group and don't capture, please add `?:`:

```
(?:http|ftp|https)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change your current code to:

```
return preg_match("~^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)?localhost~", $url);
```

You were using `{` and `}` for grouping, when those are used for quantifying and otherwise mean literal `{` and `} characters.

A couple of things to add is that:

- you can use `https?` instead of `(http|https)`;
- you can use other delimiters for the regex when your pattern has those symbols as delimiters. This avoids you excessive escaping;
- you can combine the two regex, since one part is optional (the `(?:https?|ftp)://` part) and doing so would make the later comparator unnecessary;
- the `.*` at the end is not required.